# React Native FlatList style change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using Flatlist to present my data and when I click button 1 I want to change my view! From A to B! What's the best way to do it?
I've tried render two different styles at the same time but I set one of them height 0! Also I've tried to use state to decide which style I want to show!
These two solutions work fine but I think it's kinda slow to change from A to B or B to A. 
So are there any other ways to do it? Thank you in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the concept of conditional Rendering. You can use this resource [Conditional Rendering](https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-286351816db4).

Just change the Flatlist View based on state Value using Conditional Rendering.

Comment: Yes! I tried that before but I think it's still very slow. I am not sure the problem is from Flatlist though?

Comment: It's not the Problem of the Flatlist. The Views Within the Flatlist should be designed according to your design Style 2(B).